# Average question GRE

Tags: contest-math, average, gre-exam

> The average daily temperature from 9th to 16th January(both inclusive) was 38.6 C and that from the 10th to 17th January(inclusive) was 39.2 C. what was the temperature on 17th January?

I am able to find total temperature as  308.8 C from from 9th to 16th January and 313.6 C from  the 10th to 17th January but stuck !!!

Comment: You would need to know the temperature on 9th January to solve this problem. Does the problem give other information?

Comment: No other info...

Comment: Then you cannot solve it. We can only conclude that the average temperature on 17th was 4.8 grades higher than that of 9th.

Comment: And how u arrived there?

Comment: GRE questions usually have multiple-choice answers.  Maybe some choices can be eliminated.

Answer (score 1):

The solution of this problem would require some additional information, e.g. the temperature $t_9$  on January 9th. Knowing this, and calling $t_{17}$ the temperature on January 17th, we would have

$$313.6-308.8=t_{17}-t_9$$

$$t_{17}=t_9+4.8$$